# How can I map Entity Framework TPH with identical types and Single Discriminator?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api, table-per-hierarchy

Database schema:

```
Id   int Identity NOT NULL
Name nvarchar(50) 
Discriminator nvarchar(20) NULL
```

Database data:

```
1, 'John Doe', 'Manager'
2, 'Jane Doe', 'Supervisor'
```

C# Entities:

```
public abstract class Employee 
{
    public Int32 Id {get;set;} 
    public String Name {get;set;}
} 

public class Manager : Employee { }
public class Supervisor : Employee { }
```

Why does the following mapping not work?

```
var employee = modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>();

employee.Map<Manager>(e => e.Requires("Discriminator").HasValue("Manager"));
employee.Map<Supervisor>(e => e.Requires("Discriminator").HasValue("Supervisor"));
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Strange question - *I get an error*. The only errors I get from your sample is the compile error for `modelBinder` variable (should be `modelBuilder`) and runtime error for `Employee` entity not having PK (did you miss `public int Id { get; set; }`?). Both are irrelevant to TPH.

Comment: I did type out the example and forgot to add the Id but not in the actual code.